# How do I identify the size of a byte on any platform?

Tags: c, byte, sizeof, bit

The **`sizeof(data_type)`** operator returns the *number of bytes* and not *octets*, so the size of a byte may not be 8 bits. How can one identify the size of a byte in bits on any platform?

Comment: pretty sure a byte is always 8 bits on any modern system....

Comment: I second that.   Not all platforms are byte addressable, though.   The Motorola 56K DSP can only address 24 bit words.   A most irritating platform for doing anything other than audio...

Comment: @Russ Schultz Because C does not require 8 bits == 1 byte, it can be ported to such machines.  It is because of this flexibility that caused C's early wide acceptance and also as an early choice on new esoteric platforms.  Adaptability  is a 2-edged sword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do `sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT` to determine the number of bits. Include limits.h for the definition of CHAR_BIT.

Comment: this make perfect sense to include limits.

Answer (score 0):

A byte is commonly 8 bits independent of the platform (edited based on comment below). Else you could do:

1. Set a byte (or an `int`) to `-1`.
2. Count the number of bits in the above variable (and divide by `sizeof(int)`, if you used an `int`).

Comment: "A byte should be 8 bits independent of the platform" --> not per the C spec.

Comment: Setting a byte or an int to -1 and assuming that it will be represented in 2's complement form is not portable. Isn't not?

Comment: With the vast majority of computers, this approach works expect for a few esoteric ones with padding or with non 2's complement.

Comment: @user1952500: It's portable to set an unsigned char/int/etc. to -1; that must be the maximum value of the unsigned integral type, which must be all ones since unsigned integral types must have a binary representation. (Also, the three narrow character types have no padding bits, and are always of size 1.)

Comment: @rici It makes sense that (unsigned) -1 is portable, set to all 1's similar to the unsigned overflow.. The problem description here is any type, which may include signed.

Comment: How do you propose to "count the number of bits" in `-1` ?

Comment: @M.M Using bit-arithmetic (right-shifts). I think all architectures allow for it. Since we count all bits there is no need to do the speedy counting mechanism.